# How to connect Silverlight PivotViewer control to Analysis Services cube?

Tags: silverlight, ssas, pivotviewer

How to connect a [Silverlight PivotViewer control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.pivot.pivotviewer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to an Analysis Services cube? I have a 'http pump' per the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx

Here's an example pump (from another vendor) http://demos.telerik.com/olap/msmdpump.dll